# CSS grid-column: span but only to the maximum of number of columns

Tags: css

I'm doing a responsive layout with CSS grid:

```css
#content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(240px, 1fr));
}

#content .small-item {
    grid-column: span 1;
}

#content .large-item {
    grid-column: span 2;
}
```

This works pretty well, except if the screen width ever becomes narrow enough that `auto-fill` only computes a single grid column the `.large-item` boxes still try to occupy two columns, and so of course a lot of the small items end up spilling off the side of the screen.

Is there any way of designating that a grid item should take *up to* two grid columns, but only if there are two columns to occupy?

In my specific case I could use a `@media` query with a `max-width` that overrides the `grid-column` attribute for the large items, but I'd rather have a more general solution if possible.

Comment: for now, there is no other solution than media query (or container query).

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I'll look into container queries, as that'll probably work better for the particular situation I have.